# Equation manipulation in python

Tags: python, math, equation, polynomials

Hi I want to do equation manipulation in python:
For example, I have:

```
"3x^2 + 5xy - 5 = 5x^2 + 2xy"
```

The input equation can be anything.

I need the result to be:

```
"-2x^2 + 3xy - 5 = 0"
```

I am able to extract the left hand side and right hand side of the equations and separate them. Please see the code below:

```
base_equation = raw_input()
no_spaces_equation = base_equation.replace(" ", "")
print no_spaces
left_hand_side = no_spaces[0:no_spaces.index('=')]
print left_hand_side
right_hand_side = no_spaces[no_spaces.index('=')+1:len(no_spaces)]
print right_hand_side
```

However I don't know how to check for the variables and their signs and add them. Looking forward to your help.

Thank you !

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, or do you just need to parse equations? If the latter, there are preexisting libraries for this, like SymPy.

Comment: homework assignment

Comment: You see, this goes much beyond simple string parsing. The idea here would be: you want to write a **parser** that turns your input into some kind of AST representation (abstract syntax tree). And on that tree, you can start to do all kind of evaluation, simplification, and so on. If this is some "real" homework, then it will continue, and you will be asked to exactly add such functionality. So, Xorgon is pushing you into the correct direction, but be prepared for **much** more work if you want to get things "right"!

Answer (score 2):

If you use strings it should be relatively simple.

Consider your example (I have put quote marks to ensure that it is a string):

```
"3x^2 + 5xy - 5 = 5x^2 + 2xy"
```

Clearly, you want to split it up into the different parts and then count them. In this case, x^2, xy and numbers. You can do this by analysing the string.

To make the task easy, you could be restrictive with syntax, requiring a space between each term.

Here's an example of the kind of thing you could do to group terms with some simple output formatting:

```
eqn = "3x^2 + 5xy - 5 = 5x^2 + 2xy"
split = eqn.split(" ")

terms = {}
LHS = True # We start by counting terms on the left hand side of the equation
for i in split:
    skip = False
    term = i

    if i is "=":  # Check if we've moved to the right hand side
         LHS = False

    # If the 'term' is actually a symbol and not a term
    if not term.isalnum() and term.count("^") == 0:
        continue

    stripped_digits = 0 # Keep track of the length of the coefficient

    # Remove the coefficient numbers until we get to the term we're interested in
    while term[0].isdigit() or term[0] == "-":
        term = term.lstrip(term[0])
        stripped_digits += 1
        if len(term) == 0:
            term = ""
            break
        # If the 'term' is actually a symbol and not a term
        if not term.isalnum() and term.count("^") == 0 and term != "":
            skip = True            
            break

    if skip: 
        continue

    # Find the coefficient of the term
    coeff = int(i[0:stripped_digits])

    if split[split.index(i) - 1] == "-":
        coeff = -coeff
    if term in terms.keys(): # Check if we've already started counting the term
        if LHS:
            terms[term] += coeff
        else:
            terms[term] -= coeff
    else:
        if LHS:
            terms[term] = coeff
        else:
            terms[term] = -coeff

print(terms)
# Now just format the terms as you choose
output = ""
for key in terms.keys():
    output += str(terms[key]) + key + " + "
output = output.rstrip("+ ")
output += " = 0"
print(output)
```

This outputs the following:

```
{'': -5, 'x^2': -2, 'xy': 3}
-5 + -2x^2 + 3xy = 0
```

Obviously, this isn't the most elegant solution, and I'm sure you will find more efficient ways to do most of this. But this is just a simple example of how you can consider the grouping of terms.